# running hadoop on ec2 and HADOOP_HOME variable?

Tags: 12.04, java, hadoop

I am following [Hadoop in Action](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9781935182191) to get started with hadoop with ec2. I'm running on ubuntu and have downloaded and installed the latest version of Hadoop. I am hitting a road block at this command:

```
hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster mycluster 2
```

---

> The book says "The Hadoop EC2 tools are in the directory
>   src/contrib/ec2/bin under your Hadoop installation. Recall that our
>   ec2-init.sh script has already added that directory to your system
>   PATH. Within that directory is hadoop-ec2, which is a meta-command for
>   executing other commands. To launch a Hadoop Cluster on ec2 use:
>
> **hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster < cluster-name> < number-of-slaves>**"

---

The response I get is: `hadoop-ec2: command not found`

I noticed that the variable `$HADOOP_HOME` is not set.

It looks like this book is out-dated.

1. can someone direct me to a tutorial that was created in the last couple of months on how to set up hadoop with ec2?
2. After some quick googling, it seems that `HADOOP_HOME` is deprecated. Is this true?
3. I am able to without problems execute `ec2-describe-images`. and get all the available images that I can use. Why doesn't `hadoop-ec2` command work?

Thank you for your guidance.

I know that `hadoop/bin` *shoudl* exist and when i did this:

```
sudo find / -wholename '*hadoop/bin*'
```

i found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try Amazon [EMR](http://aws.amazon.com) or [Xplenty](http://www.xplenty.com) to get a cluster automatically up and running? You may also try to provision a Hadoop cluster on EC2 with Cloudera Manager, Whirr or Ambari